# скрипт отображения ссылки только на главной

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Как вставить скрытую ссылку только на главной странице сайта?
Я вставляю в файл footer.php следующий код:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;">
Лучший сайт <a href="https://site.com/">веб сайт</a></div>
```

Но ссылка отображается на всех страницах. Как сделать так, что бы отображалась только на главной странице?

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно использовать проверку is_front_page() или is_home():

```
<?php if (is_front_page() OR is_home()) { ?>
<div style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;">
Лучший сайт <a href="https://site.com/">веб сайт</a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Выскакивает следующая ошибка - Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_home() in /var/www/site.com/data/www/site.com/templates/default/index.php on line 272

Comment: Надо сильно покорежить WP, чтобы была не определена is_home(). Она в query.php, который подключается в wp-settings.php, который подключается в последней строке wp_config.php. Ищите по цепочке, что вы сломали.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант, если is_home() поломали, можно использовать условный оператор is_front_page(), который, так же, возвращает TRUE или FALSE в зависимости от того, что отображается ли в данный момент front или пост.

```
<?php
if (is_front_page()) {
   echo("Это главная");
} else {
   echo("Это не главная");
}
?>
```

Comment: так как с помощью этого оператора опубликовать ссылку на главной?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (is_front_page()) {
   echo "<a href=\"http://example.ru/\">веб сайт</a>";
};
?>
```

Это если вставлять через шаблон. 
А вообще в ВП, для таких целей, лучше создать виджет и потом оперировать с виджетом, чем ковыряться в шаблоне.